# Unable to start activity ComponentInfo Caused by: android.view.InflateException

Tags: android, exception, button, android-selector

My android app crashes when opening certain activity and gave me the following exception :

```
02-06 10:31:53.608: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(594): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-06 10:31:53.608: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(594): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.solaceap/com.example.solaceap.RemoteTV}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #600: Error inflating class <unknown>
02-06 10:31:53.608: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(594):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1955)
02-06 10:31:53.608: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(594):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1980)
02-06 10:31:53.608: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(594):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:122)
02-06 10:31:53.608: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(594):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1146)
02-06 10:31:53.608: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(594):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-06 10:31:53.608: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(594):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-06 10:31:53.608: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(594):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
02-06 10:31:53.608: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(594):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-06 10:31:53.608: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(594):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-06 10:31:53.608: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(594):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
02-06 10:31:53.608: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(594):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
02-06 10:31:53.608: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(594):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-06 10:31:53.608: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(594): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #600: Error inflating class <unknown>
02-06 10:31:53.608: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(594):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:606)
02-06 10:31:53.608: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(594):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
02-06 10:31:53.608: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(594):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:653)
02-06 10:31:53.608: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(594):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:678)
02-06 10:31:53.608: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(594):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:739)
02-06 10:31:53.608: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(594):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:742)
02-06 10:31:53.608: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(594):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:742)
02-06 10:31:53.608: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(594):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:742)
02-06 10:31:53.608: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(594):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:742)
02-06 10:31:53.608: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(594):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:742)
02-06 10:31:53.608: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(594):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:742)
02-06 10:31:53.608: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(594):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:742)
02-06 10:31:53.608: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(594):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:742)
02-06 10:31:53.608: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(594):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
02-06 10:31:53.608: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(594):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
02-06 10:31:53.608: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(594):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
02-06 10:31:53.608: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(594):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:251)
02-06 10:31:53.608: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(594):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1835)
02-06 10:31:53.608: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(594):     at com.example.solaceap.RemoteTV.onCreate(RemoteTV.java:84)
02-06 10:31:53.608: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(594):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
02-06 10:31:53.608: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(594):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
02-06 10:31:53.608: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(594):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1919)
02-06 10:31:53.608: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(594):     ... 11 more
02-06 10:31:53.608: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(594): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
02-06 10:31:53.608: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(594):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
02-06 10:31:53.608: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(594):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
02-06 10:31:53.608: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(594):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:586)
02-06 10:31:53.608: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(594):     ... 32 more
02-06 10:31:53.608: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(594): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/remote_tv_num_buttons.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f02017f
02-06 10:31:53.608: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(594):     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1925)
02-06 10:31:53.608: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(594):     at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
02-06 10:31:53.608: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(594):     at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:2780)
02-06 10:31:53.608: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(594):     at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:445)
02-06 10:31:53.608: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(594):     at android.widget.Button.<init>(Button.java:108)
02-06 10:31:53.608: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(594):     at android.widget.Button.<init>(Button.java:104)
02-06 10:31:53.608: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(594):     ... 35 more
02-06 10:31:53.608: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(594): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/remote_tv_number_selected.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f020180
02-06 10:31:53.608: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(594):     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1925)
02-06 10:31:53.608: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(594):     at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:664)
02-06 10:31:53.608: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(594):     at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable.inflate(StateListDrawable.java:173)
02-06 10:31:53.608: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(594):     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:867)
02-06 10:31:53.608: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(594):     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:804)
02-06 10:31:53.608: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(594):     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1922)
02-06 10:31:53.608: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(594):     ... 40 more
02-06 10:31:53.608: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(594): Caused by: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file
```

This exception thrown on the `setContentView(R.layout.xml_file)` line on the `onCreate` method , and after have a loo at the exception log I found that the line **600** in the XML is probably the one that cause that,
And this is part of code that contains the line **600** in the XML which seems to cause that error:

```
          <LinearLayout
              android:id="@+id/zone_control"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:layout_gravity="center"
              android:gravity="center"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:padding="5dp"
              android:weightSum="7" >
            <Button                //this is the line 600
               android:id="@+id/one"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_marginBottom="7dp"
               android:layout_weight="1"
               android:background="@drawable/num_buttons"
               android:clickable="false"
               android:paddingRight="10dp"
               android:paddingLeft="10dp"
               android:text="1"
               android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
              <!.. another three Buttons with the same statistics !..>
            </LinearLayout>
```

And this the the `num_buttons` drawable :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item 
    android:state_selected="true" 
    android:drawable="@drawable/remote_tv_number_unselected" />
<item 
    android:drawable="@drawable/remote_tv_number_selected" />
</selector>
```

and this is `remote_tv_number_selected` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <corners android:radius="1dp"/>

    <gradient 
        android:startColor="#121212"
        android:centerColor="#212121"
        android:endColor="#353535"
        android:angle="30"/>

</shape>
```

just some flipped colors and another angle will give you the `remote_tv_number_unselected`

Comment: The error is for `@drawable/remote_tv_number_selected` in your `num_bottons` file. Make sure you have kept the `@drawable/remote_tv_number_selected` file inside `drawable` folder.

Comment: @GrIsHu yes , it's exists inside it

Comment: Please post full code of your layout file.

Comment: @MD it doesn't goes through the code, it throws the exception from the first line of the onCreate

Comment: @GrIsHu i updated my code with the containing Layout

Comment: @MD i updated my code with the containing Layout

Comment: maybe because the button has clickable="false" but you try to set a selector on it

Comment: Is this `remote_tv_number_unselected` and `remote_tv_number_selected` are images ?

Comment: they are a shapes with gradient colors

Comment: @GrIsHu i added it to the ques

Comment: @Fraggles no, i tried that before

Comment: @MRefaat The error is shown for the `remote_tv_number_selected` so please post its code.

Comment: @GrIsHu this is the one i posted, i just missed up when writing the names

Comment: @MRefaat I don't found any issue with your any of code. Can you show the java file ?

Answer (score 1):

The error was in the `android:angle` of `remote_tv_number_selected` file, as i set the angle to `30` but seems like that it doesn't accept any angles but strict ones **(0, 90, 180, 270)** , so i changed it like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <corners android:radius="1dp"/>

    <gradient 
        android:startColor="#121212"
        android:centerColor="#212121"
        android:endColor="#353535"
        android:angle="180"/>

</shape>
```